# Taking the derivative of $f(x) = x^{x^x}$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, logarithms

Let $f(x) = x^{x^x}$. I checked the derivative of this function using [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=d%2Fdx%20x%5Ex%5Ex).

I know that we can find the derivative of this by using
$$
f'(x) = e^{x^x \log(x)},
$$
to get $f'(x) = x^{x^x+x-1}(x\log^2(x) + x \log(x) + 1)$, which is the correct answer.

But if we instead use
$$
f'(x) = e^{x \log(x^x)}
$$
we get the wrong answer $f'(x) = (x^x)^x(\log(x^x) + x  + x\log(x)).$

Why do we get the wrong answer using the second approach, it seems bringing the $x$ exponent out of the log should be equivalent to bringing the $x^x$ exponent out of the log..but for some reason it isn't. Why?

Comment: Do you mean $f(x) = e^{x^{x}\log(x)}$ and $f(x) = e^{x\log(x^x)}$? In which then the second equality is not true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $\log(x^x)=x\log x$, so $x\log(x^x)=x^2\log x\not=x^x\log x$ (except, of course, when $x=1$ or $2$). It follows that, as functions, $e^{x\log(x^x)}\not=e^{x^x\log x}$.

Answer (score 3):

$e^{x\log(x^x)} = (x^x)^x$, whereas $e^{x^x\log(x)} = x^{(x^x)}$.

Comment: You should probably note that $x^x^x=x^\left(x^x\right)$

Answer (score 1):

$$u=x^x  \implies \ln u = x \ln x  \implies \frac{u'}{u}=x\frac{1}{x}+\ln x \implies u'= x^x(1+\ln x).$$ Next
$$v=x^{x^x} \implies \ln v = u \ln x \implies  \frac{v'}{v}=u'  \ln x+u \frac{1}{x}$$
$$\implies v'= v u' \ln x+\frac{uv}{x}=x^{x^x}~x^x~ [(1+\ln x)~\ln x+\frac{1}{x} ]$$

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify some of the other answers with a plot.
Part of the confusion may stem from the fact that

$$f(x) = {(x^x)}^x\\g(x) = x^{(x^x)}$$

are, in fact, different functions. This becomes particularly clear around $x=1.7$ below.

[image]